# Open and Closed Sets?

Tags: general-topology, complex-analysis

Let $f$ an entire function on $\mathbb C$. Let $S$ be an open bounded subset of $\mathbb C$. Let $K = \{ Re f(z) + Im f(z) | z \in S \} $ . Which of the following statements are correct ?

- $K$ is an open set in $\mathbb R$.
- $K$ is an closed set in $\mathbb R$.
- $K$ is an open set in $\mathbb C$.
- $K$ is a discrete set in $\mathbb C$.

I have no idea how to start this problem. Please give me any idea how to Solve . Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is: $K$ is an open set in $\mathbb{R}$.

Since $S$ be an open bounded subset of $\mathbb{C}$, $f(S)$ is open by open mapping theorem. For any $z_0\in S$, there is open ball $B(z_0,r)=\{z:|z-z_0|<r\}\subset S$, and $f(B(z_0,r))\subset f(S)$

$K$ is clearly in $\mathbb{R}$. Also $Re(f(B(z_0,r)))\leqslant|f(B(z_0,r))|$ and $Im(f(B(z_0,r)))\leqslant|f(B(z_0,r))|$. So $K$ is an open set in $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: How will conclude $K$ is open from $ Re (f (B (z_0,r)) \leq  | f(B(z_0 , r))| $ and  $ Im  (f (B (z_0,r)) \leq  | f(B(z_0 , r))| $

Comment: $Re(f(B(z_0,r)))+Im(f(B(z_0,r)))\le 2|f(B(z_0,r))|$. So for any $z\in K=\{Ref(z)+Imf(z)|z∈S\}$, there is an open interval $Re(f(B(z_0,r)))+Im(f(B(z_0,r)))$ in $f(S)$ contains $z$.

Comment: Constant functions are entire functions. But for constant functions and non-empty $S$, $K$ contains a single element, and is thus closed in $\mathbb R$ and discrete in $\mathbb C$, but open neither in $\mathbb R$ nor $\mathbb C$. Moreover, the empty set is an open bounded subset of $\mathbb C$, and for $S=\emptyset$ also $K=\emptyset$, which is both open and closed in $\mathbb R$, and open and discrete in $\mathbb C$. Your answer is correct in the case that $f$ is not constant and $S$ is not empty.